# Can I dump all Caldera form submission data into the "details" of a CiviCRM activity?

Tags: activities, activity, caldera-forms, data-processor

Caldera will email all form submission data in an email. Can I have that same form submission data added to the details field of CiviCRM activity records?

I don't see a tag to be able to do so from the CiviCRM Activity Processor, but surely this must be possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Integration of CiviCRM's Form Processor with Caldera Forms`. See https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf-civicrm-formprocessor/

Comment: I'm using https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf-civicrm/ already. Is that different than the one you referenced? Is one better than the other?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this. I've educated myself on it and understand the difference. Trying it out.

Comment: FYI there appears to be a bug preventing the creation of activities, which I've reported, but this looks promising. Thanks again.

Comment: I used this method to create activities for a number of customers. What is the bug you found. Can you share your bug-report?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "tag" but if by "Activity Processor" you mean the Email Processor then you can set the recipient email to be the email address of the email processor and it will file it in civi with the email body as the activity details. See https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/civimail/inbound/#autofiling-email-activities-via-emailprocessor

Comment: When using https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf-civicrm/, a "tag" or "magic tag" is what Caldera Forms calls fields available to be mapped in a Caldera Forms processor.  See https://calderaforms.com/doc/using-magic-tags-caldera-forms/.

Comment: Ok I see. So you could still use the Email Processor by having the form send to the email address that you set up for the Email Processor, it just wouldn't have anything to do with tags.